# What does "?fref=jewel" mean at the url of facebook?

Tags: facebook, url, analytics, fbml

I had several friend requests in facebook from profiles whose links end with "?fref=jewel". All the links had this ending term in the url. Some of the profiles were probably fake. Can anyone tell me what "?fref=jewel" means?

Answer (score 10):

It simply means that the user clicked on a notification in the notification “jewel” (that’s what FB call the thingie in the top navigation bar, where notifications are shown) to get to that address …

It is just a tracking parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook calls these icons "jewels" internally.

[image]

I suspect you clicked through to this request from a request you saw in the dropdown there?

**source** https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-a-Facebook-friend-request-has-a-URL-that-includes-fref-jewel

Answer (score 1):

I receive a lot of them, and no request from friends of friends comes with the "jewel" add. 90% of them are from girls offering sexy pictures, from guys offering sex, or african "bankers" informing that a remote cousin had an accident and there's a lot of money to get. And the other 10%, I don't bother verifying.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Mostly it means that the ip adress of same acoount carrying same person . there is most possibility of fake a/c.

Answer (score -1):

None of the answers are correct. We ran a test with someone I know to be a real account. Her friend request had the word "Jewel" at the end of the URL. So the correct answer is that all friend requests put the word Jewel in the URL.[Friend request from someone I know is a real account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruMzh.jpg)