# What does “ref=br_rs” mean in a Facebook application URL?

Tags: facebook, url, analytics, fbml

Similar to:
[What does "?ref=ts" mean in a Facebook application URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806237/what-does-ref-ts-mean-in-a-facebook-application-url)
and
[What does "?fref=jewel" mean at the url of facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040754/what-does-fref-jewel-mean-at-the-url-of-facebook?rq=1)
I'm just curious about what br_rs means in a facebook URL, I try to search some references but I don't have luck with that. Is there any API description for those kind of keywords for facebook?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As linked in your post, ?Ref=ts means you arrived at the page via **T**op **S**earch.

fref=jewel means that you arrived at that page after clicking a notification, as in, clicking the "jewel" icon.

Both are references for tracking analytics. You will see different ones based on how you arrived at that certain page.

Comment: yes that two urls are just examples that what I'm talking about, but I'm just wondering about What does “ref=br_rs” mean in a Facebook application URL? or do exists some facebook API link that explain how that keywords work? @DBoe

Comment: It's simply for analytical tracking. I dont have a a Facebook account, but if functionality is similar to other websites, they just want to know how a user arrived at a certain page. It helps focus prioritization on areas their users interact with frequent. To answer your question, no. I believe this is all for internal tracking and not involved in outward-facing APIs.